# How to correct the decimal value in swift 3?

Tags: swift

Here i need to correct the decimal value like if it is 5.1 or 5.2 ... 5.9 then it should be changed as 6 but if it is 5.0 then it should be 5 can anyone help me how to implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Foundation’s `ceil`, or `rounded(.up)`.

```
(5.0).rounded(.up) // -> 5.0
(5.1).rounded(.up) // -> 6.0
```

Or

```
import Foundation

ceil(5.0) // -> 5.0
ceil(5.1) // -> 6.0
```

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: What do you not understand? Both functions round a value up to it’s nearest whole number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`round()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/2297801-round) available in match class  you can use it like below.

```
var x = 5.2
x.round()
// x == 5.0
var y = 5.5
y.round()
// y == 6.0
var z = -5.5
z.round()
// z == -6.0
```

Update :

You can follow **@fguchelaar**'s answer or below logic

```
let myVal = 3.4
print ("myVal \(Int(myVal) + 1)")
```

But best thing is use `print ("myVal \(ceil(myVal))")` you will reach at your goal.

Comment: but i need if it is 5.1 or 5.2 then it should be changed as 6

Comment: `print ("myVal \(ceil(myVal))")` this answer fails when value is 5.0 it will makes the value as 6 but it should not do in that case

Comment: Yes I know we need to use another condition there but use **ceil()** instead of is the best way.